# Showing all subcategories when click on main category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

i want Showing all subcategories when click on main category in wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxZ9P.png)

Comment: do you want to display on widget area ?

Comment: yes, i want to widgets

Comment: What were your own efforts in solving this issue? Please add it to the issue's description.

Comment: There are some plugins available for display category and subcategory on widget area you can use that plugins